# Chosen Angular directive doesn't get updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-chosen

I've followed this great tutorial ([link](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-chosen-plugin-awesome/)) for Chosen and Angular (code is pretty much same)

Here is my directive:

```
app.angularModule.directive('chosen', function() {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var list = attrs['chosen'];

        scope.$watch(list, function () {
            element.trigger('chosen:updated');
        });

        element.chosen({ width: '350px'});
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker
    };
});
```

Here is html:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Category"  multiple class="col-lg-8 chosen-select" chosen="items"
                            ng-options="item._backingStore.Name for item in items"   ng-model="selectedCategories" >
                    </select>
```

What I  want is, when user clicks edit button, modal window pops up, and categories that where selected before clicking edit button, are selected in modal window.

Here is that part of controller:

```
  $scope.$watch(function() { return adminCrudService.getCategoriesForUpdate(); }, function() {
                $scope.action = "edit";
                $scope.categoriesForUpdate = adminCrudService.getCategoriesForUpdate();
                if ($scope.categoriesForUpdate.length > null) {
                    $scope.selectedCategories = _.filter($scope.items, function (item) {
                        return _.contains($scope.categoriesForUpdate, item);
                    });
                }
            });
```

I've logged  *$scope.selectedCategories* and everything is fine with them, but for some reason there is nothing selected in chosen.

So what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it ?

**EDIT**

I've noticed when I select some items, close modal, open it again, selected values are there again eve though i put this line inside $watch

```
$scope.selectedCategories = "";
```

**EDIT 2**

So I left this problem for a while, because I had more important things to deal with.
I've tried without chosen, i.e. using "normal" select and code works. So Definitively my chosen directive doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved it, the solution is pretty easy and straightforward actually (when you get how Angular directives work). Here is whole code for directive:

```
app.angularModule.directive('chosen', function() {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var list = attrs['chosen'];

        scope.$watch(list, function () {
            element.trigger('chosen:updated');
        });

        scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function() {
            element.trigger('chosen:updated');
        });

        element.chosen({ width: '350px'});
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker
    };
});
```

Comment: This should really be a part of the chosen directive in my opinion, forcing the user of a library to do stuff like this is just strange.

Comment: Actually, on the collection you should use `scope.$watchCollection(list, func)`, and also `$watch*` returns function to stop watching, which should be called when `$scope` destroys: `scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    unwatchModel();
                    unwatchSource();
                });`

Answer (score 1):

More expanded version of comment to previous solution.
Same as author, in HTML markup I provide source collection like `chosen="vm.myCollection"`, actually parsing `ng-options` or `ng-repeat` property with regexp is better, maybe later.
In contrast with OP, I use $watchCollection for an array, and call unwatches when scope is about to destroy.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('common.directives').directive('chosen', enterPressDirective);

    function enterPressDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                var unwatchModel = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                    elm.trigger('chosen:updated');
                });

                var unwatchSource = scope.$watchCollection(attrs.chosen, function () {
                    elm.trigger('chosen:updated');
                });

                elm.chosen();

                scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    unwatchModel();
                    unwatchSource();
                });
            }
        };
    }
}());
```