# Chosen Angular directive doesn't fire $watch for Controller As

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I followed the work of Lukas Rubalke @simpulton from [here](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-chosen-plugin-awesome/), and also found and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262442/chosen-angular-directive-doesnt-get-updated) SO post expanding on his work.

I have followed both and have the Chosen select boxes showing up. The problem I have is that I need to call 'chosen:updated' to refresh Chosen so that the data from the controller will populate the select options (data comes from a $promise / web service).

I'm using one controller to get the data and create 5 different select boxes. (5 different filter lists). I'm using Controller As syntax and ui-router.

From what I can tell it should work given the examples I followed, but the

```
element.trigger('chosen:updated');
```

is never called, and the Chosen selects, of course, do not show the options. When inspecting the DOM, the options are there, they are created from the controller data. I just can't get the call to 'updated' to fire.

This is the Directive:

```
angular.module('reporting.directive')

.directive("chosen", function () {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {
        var list = attr['chosen'];

        scope.$watch(list, function () {
            element.trigger('chosen:updated');
        });


        element.chosen({
            single_backstroke_delete: false,
            search_contains: true,
            no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
            width: "100%"
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker
    }
})
;
```

and the HTML / Template:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="filterboxtext">Cost Center</div>
    <select id="costcenter" class="chosen-select" chosen="selectsController.datacostcenter" data-placeholder="ALL" multiple
            ng-model="csSelect1" ng-options="cc2 as cc2 for cc2 in selectsController.datacostcenter"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="filterboxtext">Provider Name</div>
    <select id="providername" class="chosen-select" chosen="selectsController.dataprovname" data-placeholder="ALL" multiple ng-change="$state.forceReload()"
            ng-model="csSelect2" ng-options="provname as provname for provname in selectsController.dataprovname"></select>
</div>

<SNIP> 

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <input id="hubmenuitemdescription" value="" />
</div>
```

**EDIT**

This is the Controller

```
angular.module('reporting.controller')

.controller('SelectsController', function (SelectDataRetrival) {
    var selectsController = this;

    selectsController.datacostcenter   = SelectDataRetrival.query({ stuff: stuff });
    selectsController.dataprovname     = SelectDataRetrival.query({ stuff: stuff2 });
})
;
```

**EDIT 2**
I have confirmed that the $watch is firing the `element.trigger('chosen:updated');` before the $promise is resolved. I have the data var on scope, and am referencing it the way I understand it should be. (updated code below).

I'm still stumped as to why the `scope.$watch('selectsController.optionData', ...` does not get called when the optionData is updated (like I believe it should).

Updated Controller:

```
angular.module('reporting.controller')

.controller('SelectsController', function (SelectDataRetrival,$q) {
    var selectsController = this;

    selectsController.optionData = [];

    var datacostcenter   = SelectDataRetrival.query({ stuff: stuff });
    var dataprovname     = SelectDataRetrival.query({ stuff: stuff2 });

    $q.all([datacostcenter.$promise, dataprovname.$promise])
            .then(function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    selectsController.optionData.push(results[i]);
                }
                console.log("controller finished, data assigned"); 
            });
})
;
```

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="filterboxtext">Cost Center</div>
    <select id="costcenter" class="chosen-select" chosen data-placeholder="ALL" multiple
            ng-model="csSelect1" ng-options="cc2 as cc2 for cc2 in selectsController.optionData[0]"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="filterboxtext">Provider Name</div>
    <select id="providername" class="chosen-select" chosen data-placeholder="ALL" multiple ng-change="$state.forceReload()"
            ng-model="csSelect2" ng-options="provname as provname for provname in selectsController.optionData[1]"></select>
</div>
```

Updated Directive:

```
angular.module('reporting.directive')

.directive("chosen", function () {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {

        scope.$watch(
            function (scope) {
                return scope.selectsController.optionData
            }, function () {
                element.trigger('chosen:updated');
                console.log("fired for " + attr["id"]);
            });



        element.chosen({
            single_backstroke_delete: false,
            search_contains: true,
            no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
            width: "100%"
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker
    }
})
;
```

Comment: `attr['chosen']` evaluates to a string that will never change. `list` as a primitive value variable will never change

Comment: I added the controller code for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get this to work. I'm not 100% on the why, but I know for certain that the below changes cause the Chosen select to update, and update as expected by firing the $watch due to the data/scope changing.

I send the data into the directive in an isolate scope, and then watch that var. I also had to wait for the promise to resolve before assigning it to scope (via Controller As). If I did not wait for the promise, I would not get the update.

Directive:

```
angular.module('reporting.directive')

.directive("chosen", function () {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {

        scope.$watch("data", function () {
                element.trigger('chosen:updated');
                console.log("fired for " + attr["id"]);
            });

        element.chosen({
            single_backstroke_delete: false,
            search_contains: true,
            no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
            width: "100%"
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            data: "="
        }
    }
})
;
```

HTML / Template:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="filterboxtext">Cost Center</div>
    <select id="costcenter" class="chosen-select" chosen data-placeholder="ALL" multiple
            ng-model="csSelect1" ng-options="cc2 as cc2 for cc2 in selectsController.datacostcenter" data="selectsController.datacostcenter"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="filterboxtext">Provider Name</div>
    <select id="providername" class="chosen-select" chosen data-placeholder="ALL" multiple ng-change="$state.forceReload()"
            ng-model="csSelect2" ng-options="provname as provname for provname in selectsController.dataprovname" data="selectsController.dataprovname"></select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('reporting.controller')

.controller('SelectsController', function (SelectDataRetrival,$q) {
    var selectsController = this;

    SelectDataRetrival.query({ stuff: stuff })
        .$promise.then(function (results) {
            selectsController.datacostcenter = results;
        });
    SelectDataRetrival.query({ stuff: stuff2 })
        .$promise.then(function (results) {
            selectsController.dataprovname = results;
        });

})
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your var `list` is not bound to the `$scope` and cannot be watched. Bind it to the $scope first.

```
var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {
    scope.list = attr['chosen'];

    scope.$watch("list", function () {
        element.trigger('chosen:updated');
    });
}
```

Comment: I see the error, and see how Lukas' version followed the need for it to be on the scope. I made the change to my code, but still did not get the Chosen boxes to refresh. I added a console.log to see if the $watch was getting called, and it is. So why no options in my select? If I manually call `$('#costcenter').trigger('chosen:updated')` the options show up. I'll keep working on this, and any additional pointers would be welcome.

Comment: It seems like the $watch is getting called the first time before the $promise returns, so the array is empty and no options. Why is the $watch not getting called the second time when the $promise has resolved? What am I missing?

Comment: @ThaigoPXP thank you for you help, you got me thinking more deeply about scope.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing some useful concept of angularJS, Please refer below point.

1. **Promise** will execute only once in life time of controller call.
2. when we are applying **watch** on any variable, **watch** will trigger for all the assignment for that variable.

**var list = attr['chosen'];**

> scope.$watch(list, function () {
>               element.trigger('chosen:updated');
>           });

**list = attr['chosen again'];**

In this scenario **list** is assigned 2 times, So **watch** will trigger twice.